# SQL Sum multiple Case criteria

Tags: sql, db2

My database is on a IBM and is DB2. I have two queries that I wish to join but when I do they don't quite work.  The report is a *Rental Utilization*.

1. The first query pulls in machine info from the *CGIHIST* (History) table and the *CGIBASE* (Equipment Profile) table.
2. The second query pulls in *Rental* information.  In this query I did a `Case` statement with multiple criteria in comparing two dates.

I use *DBXTRA* as my report building tool and when I linked them, I was hoping to be able to sum the `Case` statements.  Unfortunately it won't let me.

I'm hoping to link the 1st query by the *stock number* and then sum all the values from the 2nd query `case` statement.  I tried putting a `sum` in front of the `case` but that did not work.

Any thoughts?

1st Query:

```
SELECT CBORD AS "STK", CBMSN AS "SN"
FROM PFWF0022.CGIBASE
LEFT JOIN PFWF0022.CGIHIST
ON CBORD = CHORD
WHERE CBGLIA IN('13100','13150') AND CBCAT <> '' AND CBSTA NOT IN('I','T','O','D','S','P')
GROUP BY CBORD, CBMSN 
ORDER BY cbord
limit 100
```

2nd Query:

```
SELECT RDBR AS "BR", RDCONT AS "CONT", RDSTK AS "STK", RDRDUR AS "DUR", RDPRC AS "PRC",
CASE
WHEN RDDATI = 0 AND DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4)) >= DAYS(CURRENT DATE) THEN '0'
WHEN RDDATI = 0 and DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4)) < DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) THEN '90'
WHEN RDDATI = '0' AND DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4)) >= DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) THEN DAYS(CURRENT DATE) - DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4))
WHEN DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4)) < DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) AND DAYS(substr(RDDATI, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 1, 4)) >= DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) THEN DAYS(substr(RDDATI, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 1, 4)) - DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS)
WHEN DATE(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4)) < DATE(DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS)) AND DATE(substr(RDDATI, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 1, 4)) < DATE(DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS)) THEN '0'
WHEN DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4)) >= DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) AND DAYS(substr(RDDATI, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 1, 4)) >= DAYS(CURRENT DATE - 90 DAYS) THEN DAYS(substr(RDDATI, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATI, 1, 4)) - DAYS(substr(RDDATO, 5, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 7, 2) || '/' || substr(RDDATO, 1, 4))
ELSE 555 END AS "90DAYCNT"
FROM PFWF0022.RMDETL
WHERE RDSTK <> '' 
GROUP BY RDBR, RDCONT, RDSTK, RDRDUR, RDPRC, RDDATI, RDDATO
ORDER BY RDCONT DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Why is your case statement using numbers in quotes (THEN '90', THEN '0', etc.)?

Comment: You don't explain "they don't quite work" or " putting a sum in front of the case" or "that did not work" or "linked" (joined?) or "sum the case statements" so you don't explain what it is that you want the query to do. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: 1. Quotes on 90 and 0. This is due to being self trained and not knowing the basics.

Comment: 2. I am thinking with an excel mind-frame. If I put each query into a different tab in excel then I can do a sumifs formula.  I was hoping that by linking the second query to first query I could sum the CASE statements.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what your current attempt was, besides what the error was.  Sample source/desired output data is also handy.  For joined queries, listing which column came from which table.  Some other notes: It's extremely rare to `GROUP BY` columns that aren't in the `SELECT` list.  If you have no aggregate functions, a `GROUP BY` is really `DISTINCT`.  Grouping/distinct more than ~5 columns is usually a sign of normalization issues.  `*ISO` is the only safe date format, although the conversion here is mostly unnecessary (`RDDATO` and `RDDATI` are both SARGable).